# When I use Events in Parse the listener callback is not executed, after calling the trigger with the event

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, parse-platform

I am using Parse SDK for BackboneJS and when I try to use Events, by listening to an event like this

```
object.on 'OnRender', ->
   if sessionData["is-pilot"] is "true"
    $("#notifications-list").remove()
    $("#messages-list").remove()
    $("#buidler-list").remove()
    $("#invoice-menu").remove()
    $("#logs-menu").remove()
    $(".piloty").remove()
  $(".navbar-toggle").on "click", ->
    if $("html").hasClass("nav-open")
      $("html").removeClass "nav-open"
      $("body").removeClass "nav-open"
    else
      $("html").addClass "nav-open"
      $("body").addClass "nav-open"
  LoadBrandObjects.loadBrandProductTypes()
  LoadBrandObjects.loadBrandStores()
  LoadBrandObjects.loadBrandProducts()
```

And triggering the event in this function:

```
loadNavigationBar = ->
  $(".header").load "templates/app-nav-part.html", ->
  logoURL = sessionData["brand-logo-url"] or 'images/ta3rifah1.png'

  brandName = sessionData["brand-name"] or 'Ta3rifah Client'
  if brandName.length > 30
    brandName = "#{brandName.slice(0,27)}..."
  $("#profile-menu").html "
    <img  class=\"js-brand-logo\" width=\"34\" height=\"34\" src=\"#{logoURL} \" /> 
    <div class=\"js-header-brand-name inline-block \">#{brandName}</div>
    <b class=\"caret\"></b>
  "  
  customizeNavBarForPackages()
  customizeNavBarForUser()
  # where I trigger the event ----------*******---------------
  object.trigger 'OnRender'
```

and the object extends Parse events:

```
object = {};
_.extend(object, Parse.Events);
```

But, the callback is not executed, even after the event is triggered.

I've followed their [example](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Events.html) in the docs. Is there anything that could block the event from being triggered or listened to? am I using it in a wrong way?

Here is my  [full module](https://gist.github.com/NouranMahmoud/53135987f9e65c8b4022). It runs smoothly without errors. But, the callback of `on` function isn't executed.

Comment: "doesn't work" carries no information on **how** it doesn't work. Unless you expand with *how* it doesn't work (errors, warnings or no action) - how can anyone help?

Comment: "doesn't work" means the callback code attached with `on` function is not executed.  there are no raised warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the case is `domReady` callback is getting fired after `loadNavigationBar()` so in reality you are triggering the event before listening can you can check when `app.initContents` is being called and ensure it's called after `domReady` use `console.log()` for example to check

Comment: Yes, that's right. `app.initContent()` was called before `domReady`.